# HTML5 Date Attributes on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, html, date, attributes

I am trying to add HTML5 date picker to my website in order for iOS users to be able to use the native date picker.

I need to limit the date range e.g. dates from 01/01/2015 to 07/08/2015

I am trying to use min and max attributes as suggested, however it doesn't appear to work on iPhone or iPad. Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

It may be the format of min and max. When I tried:

```
<input type="date" min="2015/01/01" max="2015/12/12" name="date">
```

It did not work. When I switched to

```
<input type="date" min="2015-01-01" max="2015-12-12" name="date">
```

It did work. In Chrome anyway. You would need to test in iOS.

Comment: I can confirm it does *not* work in iOS. You could limit the dates via JavaScript.